# foreach loop not returning expected results

Tags: perl, loops, hash

I wrote a script below to analyze two file formats from [bedtools](http://bedtools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/content/tools/getfasta.html?highlight=name) (-tab option, -name option) so it could combine the headers if the sequences match. The problem I ran into was that if the sequences matched to multiple names it only printed one of the names that correspond to it. I was wondering if anyone had a suggestion to how to approach this. As I want both the position of the sequence and name. Is there an option through bedtools?

My script stores both files into their own hashes and then loops through then if they are equal it is suppose to print out matches in sequences with the appropriate names. It does this but it does not give errors if multiple sequences correspond to the name, it simply does not print them. So my conclusion is that the foreach loop is failing syntax wise in some form I am not noticing. Any suggestions? Cheers.

sample data: -name output bedtools

```
     >sequence_a
     AGGT
     >sequence_b
     AAAA
     >sequence_c
     CCCC
     >sequence_d
     AAAA
```

sample data: -tab output bedtools

```
    >1-5
    AAAA
    >10-14
    ACCT
    >15-19
    CCCC
```

expected output from script

```
    >sequence_b|1-5
    AAAA
    >sequence_c|15-19
    CCCC
    >sequence_d|1-5
    AAAA
```

Script

```
my %sequence;

open(NAMES_FILE, $ARGV[0]) or die "Cannot open the file: $!";
my $hash_key_name;
my $hash_value_name;
while (my $line = <NAMES_FILE>) {
    if ($line =~ /^>(\S+)/) {
    $hash_key_name = $1;
    }
    elsif ($line =~ /\S/) {
    chomp $line;
    $hash_value_name = $line;
    $sequence{$hash_key_name} = $hash_value_name;
    }
}


my %sequence_2;
open (POSITIONS_FILE, $ARGV[1]) or die "Cannot open the file: $!";
my $hash_key_pos;
my $hash_value_pos;
while (my $line2 = <POSITIONS_FILE>) {
    if ($line2 =~ /^>(\S+)/) {
    $hash_key_pos = $1;
    }
    elsif ($line2 =~ /\S/) {
    chomp $line2;
    $hash_value_pos = $line2;
    $sequence_2{$hash_key_pos} = $hash_value_pos;
    }
}


foreach $hash_key_pos (keys %sequence_2) {
     foreach $hash_key_name (keys %sequence) {
         if ($sequence{$hash_key_name} eq $sequence_2{$hash_key_pos}){
            print ">$hash_key_name|$hash_key_pos\n$sequence{$hash_key_name}\n"}
    }
}
```

Comment: I would imagine that there is a problem with your hash keys, rather than with your syntax.  Put a print statement in each loop to see what's in the hashes. Especially there should probably be an `else` clause in the final loop with a warning message when the hashes don't match. (I would substantially refactor this code to have less repetition and fewer short-lived variables, but that's really outside the scope of your question, and also depends on where you want to go with this code.)

Comment: The final loop especially is extremely inefficient.  If you had a top-level hash with all your keys like `$hash{$key}{"name"}` and `$hash{$key}{"pos"}` it would be much simpler and more efficient.

Comment: I already had a print statement in it to check the hash contents, I took it out for the purpose of posting my script here. My apologies.

Comment: Efficiency is something I been trying to work on, thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hashes will happily overwrite values, saving only the latest value, without throwing errors. If you want to catch that, you will need to put an explicit check in to see if the hash has a value before you overwrite it, something like:

```
while (my $line = <NAMES_FILE>) {
        if ($line =~ /^>(\S+)/) {
            $hash_key_name = $1;
        }
        elsif ($line =~ /\S/) {
            chomp $line;
            $hash_value_name = $line;
            if (defined($sequence{$hash_key_name}) && $sequence{$hash_key_name} ne $hash_value_name) {
                die("multiple sequences match $hash_key_name: $sequence{$hash_key_name}, $hash_value_name");
            }
            $sequence{$hash_key_name} = $hash_value_name;
        }
}
```

That being said, it would be most helpful if you could provide sample data which produced the error you are trying to catch. It looks as if the data above should not contain this error.

Comment: Im having trouble uploading sample data as the sequences are too long. How do you suggest I show you the sample data?

Comment: I solved my problem! Thanks.... I didn't realize a lot of the data was actually repeated.... so it only gave me one return for it... made it seem like I was missing a lot!
Thanks for showing me how to kill something if there is an error. (your format for killing is much better than mine)

Comment: Thanks. There's a book called "Modern Perl", in it's second or third edition now, which can be helpful in getting up to speed with the latest techniques, capabilities and idioms of perl programming.