# best way to merge every other line from two different files

Tags: perl, concatenation, lines

I am attempting to combined every other line in two files. I tried to adapt an old script of mine, linked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32344307/foreach-loop-not-returning-expected-results) by using hashes. The best way to explain this is by showing an example, can't really word it well. If you have further questions about my task please comment below and I will clarify.

File 1:

```
>blue
it is a 2006 toyota
>red
it is a 1990
>black
it is a mongoose
>blue
it is a 2010
```

File 2:

```
>car
it is a 2006 toyota
>jeep
it is a 1990
>bike
it is a mongoose
>jeep
it is a 2010
```

Expected Output:

```
>blue|car
it is a 2006 toyota
>red|jeep
it is a 1990
>black|bike
it is a mongoose
>blue|jeep
it is a 2010
```

The problem I was having with the old script was that it would delete any repeated elements and I don't want to repeat occurrences. Since in my actual file the second line from the both files is the same (line 2 in file 1 is the same as line 2 in file2). I am not experienced with perl one liners but I think a one liner can accomplish this task much faster than my script.

Comment: Are both files the same length? Are the common lines in between exactly the same in both files?

Comment: The files are both the same length, identical expect for the lines I'm combining. As for the lines in between no. I will edit them to be representative of the file. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl --
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $in1, "<", 'file1.txt' or die $!;
open my $in2, "<", 'file2.txt' or die $!;

while (<$in1>) {

    chomp;
    print;

    my $file2line = <$in2>;
    print "|", substr($file2line,1);

    my $whatitis  = <$in1> or last;
    <$in2> || undef; # throw file2's line away

    print $whatitis;
}

close $in1;
close $in2;
```

**Output:**

```
$ more file1.txt 
>blue
it is a 2006 toyota
>red
it is a 1990
>black
it is a mongoose
>blue
it is a 2010
$ more file2.txt 
>car
it is a 2006 toyota
>jeep
it is a 1990
>bike
it is a mongoose
>jeep
it is a 2010
$ perl script2.pl
>blue|car
it is a 2006 toyota
>red|jeep
it is a 1990
>black|bike
it is a mongoose
>blue|jeep
it is a 2010
$
```